# What's different in the British English translation of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I see that Minecraft 1.1 adds foreign language translations, including separate translations for US English and British English. Are there any differences between the two? If so, what are they?

Comment: I'd assume the common differences between British English and US English. Some words, such as color vs colour, are spelled differently, etc, etc. The list goes on and on. They are very minor, and you could probably still read it perfectly fine either way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number of regional differences (e.g. "grey" vs. "gray", "odour" vs. "odor" and use of the [Oxford comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)), but there are also a number of what seem to be completely spurious changes (capitalization, "Your demo" vs. "The demo").  Also note that, internally, the UK translation is mis-assigned to the `en_CA` (Canadian) language code and is stored as `en_CA.lang`.  The reverse is also true; "Canadian English" is stored in `en_GB.lang`.  (The Canadian localization also appears to be an inconsistent mishmash of the US and GB localizations, to the point of having "**Grey** Wool" but "**Gray** Dye".)

Full list of significant differences between the US and GB localizations:

```
US language.code=en_US
GB language.code=en_CA
US language.region=US
GB language.region=UK
US achievement.killEnemy.desc=Attack and destroy a monster
GB achievement.killEnemy.desc=Kill a monster
US achievement.snipeSkeleton.desc=Kill a skeleton with an arrow from more than 50 meters
GB achievement.snipeSkeleton.desc=Kill a skeleton with an arrow from more than 50 metres
US demo.reminder=The demo time has expired, buy the game to continue or start a new world!
GB demo.reminder=Your demo time has expired, buy the game to continue or start a new world!
US enchantment.arrowDamage=Power
GB enchantment.arrowDamage=Damage
US enchantment.arrowFire=Flame
GB enchantment.arrowFire=Fire
US generator.flat=Superflat
GB generator.flat=Super-Flat
US gui.toMenu=Back to title screen
GB gui.toMenu=Back to the title screen
US item.dyePowder.gray.name=Gray Dye
GB item.dyePowder.gray.name=Grey Dye
US item.dyePowder.silver.name=Light Gray Dye
GB item.dyePowder.silver.name=Light Grey Dye
US item.leggingsCloth.name=Leather Pants
GB item.leggingsCloth.name=Leather Trousers
US menu.returnToMenu=Save and Quit to Title
GB menu.returnToMenu=Save and quit to title
US potion.prefix.odorless=Odorless
GB potion.prefix.odorless=Odourless
US selectWorld.mapFeatures.info=Villages, dungeons etc
GB selectWorld.mapFeatures.info=Villages, dungeons, etc.
US stat.diveOneCm=Distance Dove
GB stat.diveOneCm=Distance Dived
US tile.cloth.gray.name=Gray Wool
GB tile.cloth.gray.name=Grey Wool
US tile.cloth.silver.name=Light Gray Wool
GB tile.cloth.silver.name=Light Grey Wool
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this isn't a UK difference, but if you switch to Canadian and try to sleep, instead of "You can only sleep at night." it says "Sorry, you can only sleep at night." It uses the "Canadians are polite" stereotype.